# Как убрать margin в почтовых клиентах для html писем из outlook?

Tags: html, вёрстка, email, outlook, margin

Я сверстал подпись для outlook, которое везде отображается хорошо, кроме mail.ru и android gmail.
К стилям параграфа в этих клиентах добавляются отступы от user agent и ничего не получается с ними сделать.

```
p {
display: block;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px; }
```

При этом письмо соответственно выглядит растянутым сверху-вниз, т.к. outlook автоматом оборачивает любой текст или изображение в параграф, на что я никак не могу повлиять. Даже если просто вставить текст в ячеку таблицы, то outlook дополнительно потом обернет текст сначала "p", а затем "span".

Я пробовал делать дополнительную обертку, чтобы задать font-size:0 для родителя или просто добавлял это правило в любой элемент таблицы верхнего уровня, но outlook все это удаляет при отправке. Установка правила font-size:0 в тег style в head тоже не дает результата.

Принудительная установка margin:0!important;margin:0; для параграфа или в тег style также не дает результата.

Для некоторых писем я вижу что в конце тела письма mail.ru вставляет такой код прямо перед закрывающимся тегом div:

```
<style>.MsoNormal_mr_css_attr{margin:0;}</style>
```

Это соответственно исправляет проблему, но я никак не могу этим воспользоваться т.к. не понимаю по какому принципу mail.ru добавляет такие стили и в моем письме данный код отсутствует.

В gmail android судя по всему такая же проблема, но я не могу никак испектировать код из приложения, поэтому не знаю какие там классы и отступы точно добавляются, но выглядит оно также растянуто как в mail.ru только чуть менее.

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? я уже 2 дня бьюсь над этим решением

Целиком сверстанную подпись можно посмотреть по [ссылке в OneDrive](https://68mac-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/29_68mac_onmicrosoft_com/EudjNoIAZ4dApu1Mg3wlsvMBi4W8e6T2BzGSH6HL5Bb4ig?e=LguMnJ)

Comment: обычно письма верстаются на таблицах и тегам таблиц задаются отсупы

Comment: Мое письмо сверстано таблицами. Я указал, что даже если просто вставить текст в ячейку таблицы "td", то после отправки такой код обработается через outlook и получатель получит ячейку таблицы, а в ней все равно еще параграф и спан "td - p - span"
К "p" как раз и добавляются margin, которые я пытаюсь убрать

Comment: пробовали добавлять !important?

Comment: Добавление ! important не решает проблему

Comment: Познакоьтесь с codepen или jsfiddle, ну есть же песочницы